# Is it possible to create multiple prefix in AWS S3 LifeCycle

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS life cycle management , can we create one rule with multiple prefix   .
I went through this blog https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/manage-lifecycle-using-dot-net.html

but this documentation shows example of only  one rule and  one prefix

is there any other way i can create multiple prefix by having only one rule.

There is one more option like  Tag , which i don't know  how it works or can it be helpful in achieving my goal

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use one prefix per rule, but you can add multiple rules with only the prefixes changed. There is even an example in the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html):

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <Filter>
           <Prefix>projectA/</Prefix>
        </Filter>
        transition/expiration actions.
         ...
    </Rule>

    <Rule>
        <Filter>
           <Prefix>projectB/</Prefix>
        </Filter>
        transition/expiration actions.
         ...
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Tagging means you can attach tags to *objects* and the lifecycle rule will apply to objects that have that particular tag. From the same docs:

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <Filter>
           <Tag>
              <Key>key</Key>
              <Value>value</Value>
           </Tag>
        </Filter>
        transition/expiration actions.
        ...
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

In this case, the rule is effective for objects that have key=value tags. More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html

Comment: Thank your for replying, Can you please let me know if i can get C# equivalent code found for creating Tags from C# code, i found this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Write-S3LifecycleConfiguration.html

Comment: I don't use c# so unfortunately I can't provide any resources for that. But I'm sure the SDK has a corresponding operation

Comment: which language do you use, or is there any other way do it

Comment: The NodeJS call is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObjectTagging-property . And the CLI is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html . I'm sure there is a function for this for c# also